# Cannot evaluate expression error

Tags: c#

While debugging my application, I am getting the error as "Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.". I have googled for this error but could not find the code, where the error happens. But in my case, it is not showing where the error is stuck.

And it shows a picture like this:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest any further step I can take to drill down the source of this overflow. I have completed coding part in my application..But unfortunately can not debug. Any ideas would be really appreciated...

Just now I am noticing that I have some files(.cs) which has only code, but no design. Will that result in such a stackoverflow exception?

Comment: You need to post some code. You can debug a bit - this is screen shot is coming from the debugger. What does the call stack show? Is it calling the same function recusively?

Comment: As VS says, you got a `StackOverflowException`, so you cannot evaluate any expression. First, fix the exception. Post the code that caused the exception, here, so the people can help you.

Comment: you are probably stuck in an infinite loop. probably, a rogue condition, never satisfying. look for all those sections of code, dealing with a while or for loop, or a recursive function call

Comment: @doctorlove:While examining callstack it shows like:"> Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStud‌​io.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x5a bytes".What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not anything with recursive functions or if conditions..I was calling multiple objects at the same time in my application, which resulted in StackOverflowException..I made some modifications in my program.Now it works fine..Thanks guys for all your support...

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you have something like this in your code:

```
private T field;

public T Field
{
    get
    { 
         return Field; // note the capital F, causing recursion and eventually a StackOverflowExcpetion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `StackOverflowException` is an unrecoverable error. You can't evaluate anything at that point, but the call-stack of your current thread will probably clearly indicate the cause.

Examine the call-stack and modify your code appropriately - most likely, you have an infinite recursion (or you have self-referential markup/xml/similar that is causing a .NET library to infinitely recurse).

Comment: While examining callstack it shows like:"> Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x5a bytes".What does this mean?