# unable to fix StackOverFlowException

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow

I've already been trying for weeks to fix this exception in my app (WinForms). The problem is, the code is over 4k lines long, and I still have absolutely no idea where is the problem that causes the exception. However, I have noticed one thing (that is sadly the only clue now). When the users report the application crash, it is usually after like 5-15 minutes of runtime (never more than about 20 minutes). But when I run it in debug of Visual Studio, I can keep it running for 5 hours with no problem. Does anyone have any idea what this strange thing could mean?
Or any other useful tips how to trace where the exception is thrown?

Comment: there could dozens of reasonso for this. Can try: 1) compile your app in DEBUG 2) Run it like EXE (no from VS) 3) Attach with debugger , if still can not get problem, try to run the same app on client machine "so in production" and attach with remote debugging (if this is possible)

Comment: We will need way more information. What is the architecture of the application (x64/x86)? What machine is the client running with. What is your dev machine? What is the code doing - looping?

Comment: any background running thread is used in application ...

Comment: Recursive calls are always a good thing to check. Also, don't you have any logging?

Comment: The architecture is x86, and no threading - everything runs in just one thread..
As for the "what is the app looping" - that's the thing, pretty much everything.. But mainly string values read from an XML document, and I think there are few loops with the form controls

Comment: Can you build a debug version to get a stacktrace of the exception? Even in release you could build with pdb.

Comment: Although I have checked the recursives before, just found one quite suspicios method. Recursive call deleted, waiting for result.

Comment: Have a look at here also..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378170/cannot-evaluate-expression-error/18415990#18415990